# Laravel: How can I submit GET form redirect to specific route with parameter

Tags: php, laravel

How to pass the pass the parameter to route when the option is selected? The route will redirect to the selected membership editing page.

[image]

**Blade**

```
{!! Form::open(['id' => 'member-form', 'route' => ['memberships.edit', $member_id], 'method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'wizard-validation']) !!}
@csrf
    <div class="form">
        {!! Form::select('member_id', $members, $member_id, [
              'id' => 'member_id',
              'class' => 'form-control select2',
              'placeholder' => 'Type to Search']) 
        !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Below is the member list `$members` from select option.

```
array:5 [▼
  1 => "2000010000 : George"
  2 => "2000020000 : Lisa"
  3 => "2000030000 : James"
  4 => "2000040000 : Kelly"
  5 => "2000050000 : Steve Smith"
]
```

**Route**

Route redirect to display member's data / edit the members.

```
Route::middleware('auth')->prefix('memberships')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/edit/{membership}', [MembershipController::class, 'edit'])->name('memberships.edit');
});
```

**Script**

This script is to submit the form once the user click the any option from member listing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#member_id').bind('change', function() {
            if (this.value) {
                $('#member-form').attr('action', '/memberships/edit/' + $(this).val());
                $('#member-form').submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just do this with a button? Give it a href like `member/edit/{member_id}`?

Comment: @geertjanknapen Because I need it redirect to member details page after select the member from the select option list

Comment: Yeah but using a button will do exactly the same, instead of selecting from list you click a button with perhaps the member name or something.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `window.location` to the URL you want to redirect to, something like this:

```
    $('#member_id').bind('change', function() {
        if (this.value) {
            window.location = '/memberships/edit/' + $(this).val()
        }
    });
```